# Using two and’s in one sentence, and starting a sentence with “To”

Tags: prepositional-phrases, sentence-starts, syntactic-analysis, run-on-sentence, and-and

Is this sentence correct?

> To view your policy status, last payment information and next payment information, enter your policy number in the box below and click Submit to continue.

I’m not a fan of starting a sentence with a preposition. I **believe** it’s ok, but I’m not completely certain.  Also, I don’t like the use of the word *and* twice there in the same sentence like that.

I would rewrite and structure the sentence differently.  It also feels like a run-on sentence to me, but I’m no expert and have been out of school for a long time now.

I was curious so I Googled it and this site came up, so I decided to post a question see what response I got.

Comment: Welcome :-) As you can see, a more-or-less "bare" question just asking "is the sentence correct" is not really the best sort of question to ask here. I have a couple of questions for **you**: What do _you_ think is wrong with this sentence? What about it bothers you? Where else have you looked to see whether it might be right? What did those sources have to say, and why did they not answer your question. **Put the answers to these questions back in your original post** by [editing it](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/185218/edit) and then we'll get you a better answer!

Comment: What do you mean by “correct”? Are you concerned with grammar or orthography or style?  Many of us would certainly add a comma but that isn’t a matter of the sentence structure as you would have it.

Comment: I’ve tried to edit your question to make what you’re asking clearer.  If in so doing I’ve accidentally misrepresented your question, then I’m sorry and you should please feel perfectly free to edit it yourself so that it says what you meant it to say.

Comment: Is the sentence structurally sound?

Comment: I would add that while there's nothing wrong with starting a sentence with a preposition, *to* is not a preposition here.

Comment: "Structurally sound" is not a term with a clear meaning, you'll have to be more precise. The sentence is grammatically and syntactically impeccable, and it's still not quite clear why you think it might not be. A run-on sentence is [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence), and as choster says, there is nothing wrong with starting a sentence with a preposition (which is why it is possible in the first place), but that is not even relevant here as your sentence does *not* begin with a preposition. The rest of the question is a duplicate, and I am closing it as such.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the knowledge.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: "To the victor the spoils!", "To each his own.", "From each according to his ability, to each according to his need.", "From where the sun now stands, I shall fight no more forever.", "Despite everything, I believe that people are really good at heart", "Unto us a boy is born, king of all creation..." - all perfectly good sentences.  Whence springs your objection to them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct.  There is nothing wrong with using "and" more than once in a sentence.

In a single list you would not normally use more than one conjunction ("apples and oranges and pears"), but even then it is not wrong, just more words than you need.  It is quite common in verse ("lions and tigers and bears, oh my!").

Comment: Although it gets interesting/complicated when a list contains compound items. “We have two flavors of ice cream: strawberries and cream, and peanut butter and fudge.” See [Is “between _X_ ***or*** _Y_” valid?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/137700/26083)